# ace editor tutorial with save function

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I need to add save function to my [ACE editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) tutorial. Here is my sample code. Please help me to add save event to my sample code. please do not down vote me.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

```css
#editor { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width :600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="editor">
  function foo(items) {
  var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
  return x;
  }
</div>
```

Comment: `add save event to my sample code` Do you mean save to the server?

Comment: yes. i need to save code in the server. Ctrl + S

Comment: I can answer you that without the save function in the server because it depends the server technology and the logic you want (save to file or db). It will be OK?